# Can't Install Raspbian Because SD Card Shrunk

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I have an 8 GB Kingston SD card that I'm using. I formatted the card with the formatter from sdcard.org and it kept its file size after format. I downloaded the NOOBS 3.2.1 file from RaspberryPi's website onto my Windows 10 computer and extracted it onto the SD card. Still had the same size. I put it into the Pi and started it up. It had a box saying "Resizing FAT Partition" for about 10 minutes. After this, the install menu showed up, but it says I only have 5,208 MB of free space. I understand that Linux will create other partitions after it's installed, but mine happened before and in a way that I can't even install Raspbian as it's 5623 MB. How am I supposed to install it if it doesn't even give itself enough space?

Comment: That's because Windows can't see the EXT4 partitions so it assumes they don't exist. Format the card in your phone, camera or tablet and all will be good.

Comment: My computer isn't doing the installation though, NOOBS is. NOOBS is what changes the size to something that it can't use. Windows has no problem with viewing the card before I turn it on in the pi.

Comment: Are you using NOOBS 3.2.1 downloaded on Windows, unzipped and copied to a blank 32GB (or smaller SDCard)?

Comment: I am using NOOBS 3.2.1 downloaded onto windows 10, unzipped directly into a blank formatted 8 GB Kingston SD Card. I use the same formatter that Pi's site directly suggests.

Comment: Check your SDCard isn't a fake.